# Cygwin installation issue on Windows server 2016 - exit 256

Tags: cygwin

I'm getting an issue (**exit code 256**) with cygwin installation (version 2.90) on Windows Server 2016 from http://mirros.kernel.org.

I'm experienced with cygwin installation and have installed it on Win Server 2008, 2012, 2016 many times. I see this issue for the first time. System variables path has been set to `D:\bin`. Installation to root of D: drive.

**Error**

```
*Package: 0/Perpetual 
    0p_000_autorebase.dash exit code -1073741819
    0p_texlive_prep.dash exit code -1073741819
-   0p_update-info-dir.dash exit code -1073741819
Package: _/coreutils</br>
    coreutils.sh exit code 256</br>
Package: _/bash</br>
    bash.sh exit code 256
Package: _/a2ps
    a2ps.sh exit code 256
Package: _/base-cygwin
    000-cygwin-post-install.sh exit code 256
Package: _/base-files
    base-files-mketc.sh exit code 256
    base-files-profile.sh exit code 256
Package: _/p11-kit
    p11-kit.sh exit code 256
Package: _/ca-certificates
    ca-certificates.sh exit code 256
Package: _/crypto-policies
    crypto-policies.sh exit code 256
Package: _/libssl1.1
    openssl.sh exit code 256
Package: _/email
    email.sh exit code 256
Package: _/gv
    gv.sh exit code 256
Package: _/html2ps
    html2ps.sh exit code 256
Package: _/libfontconfig-common
    fontconfig_dtd.sh exit code 256
Package: _/libgdk_pixbuf2.0_0
    gdk-pixbuf2.0.sh exit code 256
Package: _/libnss3
    nss.sh exit code 256
Package: _/libpaper-common
    libpaper.sh exit code 256
Package: _/libsasl2_3
    libsasl2_3.sh exit code 256
Package: _/libssl1.0
    openssl10.sh exit code 256
Package: _/libxml2
    libxml2.sh exit code 256
Package: _/man-db
    man-db.sh exit code 256
Package: _/mintty
    mintty.sh exit code 256
Package: _/mutt
    mutt.sh exit code 256
Package: _/openssh
    openssh.sh exit code 256
Package: _/tcp_wrappers
    tcp_wrappers.sh exit code 256
Package: _/tcsh
    tcsh.sh exit code 256
Package: _/texinfo-tex
    texinfo-tex.sh exit code 256
Package: _/wget
    wget.sh exit code 256
Package: _/texlive-collection-basic
    texlive-collection-basic.sh exit code 256
Package: _/texlive-collection-latex
    texlive-collection-latex.sh exit code 256
Package: _/vim-common
    vim.sh exit code 256
Package: _/xinetd
    xinetd.sh exit code 256
Package: z/Perpetual
    zp_desktop-file-utils.sh exit code 256
    zp_fontconfig_cache_1.sh exit code 256
    zp_glib2.0.sh exit code 256
    zp_man-db.sh exit code 256
    zp_shared-mime-info.sh exit code 256
    zp_texlive_finish.dash exit code -1073741819*
```

Can you please advise in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a programming question however:

- Installation on root of Windows drive is NOT reccommended

https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.c

D: or C: is the same...

- The latest Cygwin 3.1.0 to 3.1.2 has a bug that make installation fails in that position.

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2020-01/msg00129.html

Use a proper directory like `D:\Cygwin64`